# response.writeHead and response.end in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

1. Can anyone explain me why do we call the `writeHead` and `end`
   method in createServer method.
2. What is the main purpose of options object passed in createServer
   method.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Those calls to `writeHead` and `end` are not being done in the `createServer`method, but rather in a callback.

It's a bit easier to see if you split out the callback into a separate function:

```
function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}

https.createServer(options, handleRequest).listen(8000);
```

So here we define a `handleRequest` function and then pass that into the `createServer` call. Now whenever the node.js server we created receives an incoming request, it will invoke our `handleRequest` method.

This pattern is very common in JavaScript and is core to node.js' asynchronous event handling.

Comment: `writeHead` writes the HTTP header (status code 200), `end` writes the body and closes the response. Did you check the API documentation?

Comment: It's not a callback, it's listener to be bind to server's `request` event. Also, http://nodejs.org/api/http.html got all the answers to [`res.writeHead`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers), [`res.write`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding), [`res.end`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding)  and other [`req`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverrequest) / [`res`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) stuff.

Comment: But it still doesnt answer the question. The code you wrote still runs even without the writeHead method. Can you please explain why? Thanks

Comment: there should be a reason object in `writeHeader` method ,isn't it?      ex:`response.writeHead(200,{"context-type":"text/plain"}); response.write("this has no erros,okk"); response.end();`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question.

Answer (score 21):

In your code, the `writeHead()` is called to write the header of the response, that the application will serve to the client. The `end()` method both sends the content of the response to the client and signals to the server that the response (header and content) has been sent completely. If you are still going to send anything else, you should call `write()` method of `res` response object instead.

The `options` JSON object is a modifier that you may use, to override the default behaviour of the `createServer()` method. In your code's case:
+ key: Private key to use for SSL (default is null)
+ cert: Public x509 certificate to use (default is null)

You can find more in [this section](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) of the Node.js API doc about the `response.writeHead()` method.
You can find more in [this section](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) of the Node.js API doc about the `https.createServer()` method.

Comment: I just asumed that you have a reasonable idea of how HTTP works. Please feel free to ask further if you do not understand that.

Comment: What will happen if I don't add `end()` but just `writeHead()` only

Comment: @DunDev Since you never tell the server to send the message, presumably the message is never sent. What exactly happens after the message is never sent depends on a variety of things, including if you've got timeouts set up (so if a message remains unreplied-to for too long, it's automatically errored out) and what options the client specifies.

Answer (score 4):

`response.writeHead(200)` sends a response header to the request. The status code is a 3-digit HTTP status code, like 404.

This method must only be called once on a message and it must be called before response.end() is called.

If you call response.write() or response.end() before calling this, the implicit/mutable headers will be calculated and call this function for you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know if you don't put the response.end() at the end then your web page will go on loading thus the response.end() is used to tell the server that the data has been loaded

Answer (score 0):

The `res.writeHead` method is for returning a status code to the browser, and the browser will throw an error if it is a client-side status code or server-side status code. The `res.end` method is to make sure the response isn't returned before it might be ready, in case of nested code or otherwise.

The purpose of the `options` object is to make sure the page has a valid key and certificate *before* declaring that the page is encrypted under https.