# How to pass an array from one function to another as reference in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, geofire

I have one function `getUsers` where I have one array `jsonResponse`. I am passing that array to `computeData` function. I want `computeData` function should be able to add items in `jsonResponse` array itself.

But below code is not adding in same array, as it always return empty array in `response.send` function.

index.js

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  var x = [];

  var xLocation,
    yLocation = [],
    jsonResponse = [];

  // print algorithm name
  console.log(request.query.algo);

  let geoFire = new GeoFire(db.ref("/users/" + request.query.userId));

  geoFire.get("location").then(function(location) {
    xLocation = location;
  });

  db
    .ref("/users/" + request.query.userId)
    .once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      var jsonObject = snapshot.val();
      var basicProfileJsonObject = jsonObject.basicProfile;
      for (var key in basicProfileJsonObject) {
        if (utils.isNumber(basicProfileJsonObject[key])) {
          x.push(basicProfileJsonObject[key]);
        }
      }
      db.ref("/users/").once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        var y = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
          var user = item.val();
          let userId = user.basicProfile.userId;
          if (userId !== request.query.userId) {
            if (xLocation == null) {
              computeData(x, user, request.query.algo, jsonResponse);
            } else {
              let geoFire = new GeoFire(db.ref("/users/" + userId));
              geoFire.get("location").then(function(location) {
                if (location === null) {
                  console.log(
                    "Provided key is not in GeoFire, will ignore profile"
                  );
                  computeData(x, user, request.query.algo, jsonResponse);
                } else {
                  console.log("Provided key has a location of " + location);
                  var distance = GeoFire.distance(xLocation, location); // in km
                  console.log("Distance: " + distance);

                  if (distance < 15) {
                    computeData(x, user, request.query.algo, jsonResponse);
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });
        response.send(jsonResponse);
      });
    });
});

function computeData(x, user, algo, jsonResponse) {
  var similarityCount,
    y = [];

  var basicProfileJsonObject = user.basicProfile;
  for (var key in basicProfileJsonObject) {
    if (utils.isNumber(basicProfileJsonObject[key])) {
      y.push(basicProfileJsonObject[key]);
    }
  }

  if (algo === "cosine") {
    // compute cosine value
    similarityCount = cosineUtils.cosineSimilarity(x, y);
  } else if (algo == "euclidean") {
    // compute euclidean distance value
    similarityCount = 1 / (1 + euclidean(x, y));
  } else if (algo === "pearson-correlation") {
    // compute pearson correlation coefficents
    similarityCount = pcorr.pearsonCorrelation(x, y);
  }
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
  console.log(similarityCount);
  jsonResponse.push(user);
}
```

Does anyone know how to pass array as reference and add items into it in Cloud Function for Firebase ?

Comment: That should work.  Have you tried logging the contents of jsonResponse before you send it and checking to see if it is what you think?

Comment: it is empty before I sent it into `computeData`, I tried log `jsonResponse` in `computeData` which print array which I add in `computeData` which is perfect. but it sends empty response here `response.send(jsonResponse);` that's mean it is not adding in same array :/ not sure if items is in array. Is this because `response.send(jsonResponse);` execute before execution of `computeDate` ?

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal example of what isn't working the way you expect.  Right now there is apparently a lot of code missing from computeData that could be incorrect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added code, can you check it now please. I see that it is adding items in an array but it is sending empty response. what's wrong ? it should send array which I am adding in the response

Comment: Can you show a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem passing an array to a function?  This is essentially the code from your other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532895/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-in-firebase-cloud-function

Comment: @DougStevenson can you check in question. I added complete code. It is sending an array and adding is also working fine, but why it is sending empty response, I am sending array in response. I am not sure what I am doing wrong :/

Comment: does it go in your first `if (xLocation == null) { compute` statement?

Comment: @grgmo nope, it always goes in else part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` statement is a `promise` which means your loop would have finished and called `response.send(jsonResponse);` by the time it gets to `computeData()` in your else statement.

Try something like this, it doesn't touch all your variables but the main idea is to use `Promise.all` with computed values as `resolved` -

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // blah blah
  var y = []; // store promises that resolves your computed value
  snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
    // blah blah
    if (xLocation == null) {
      y.push(Promise.resolve(computeData());
    } else {
      y.push(computeAnotherData(userId));
    }
  });

  Promise.all(y)
    .then(values => {
      response.send(values);
    });
});

function computeAnotherData(userId) {
  let geoFire = new GeoFire(db.ref("/users/" + userId));
  return geoFire.get("location").then(function(location) {
    return computeData();
  });
}
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I think this is the problem. It is going in else part. and sending empty response. Do you know how I can solve it ?

Comment: I did as you suggested, you can see updated code here https://pastebin.com/QmTnbFmt now it returns `[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]` in response can you check whats wrong in updated code

Comment: it looks like you're not returning anything from `computeData()`?