# Pass value from http.request or superagent to http.createServer NodeJs

Tags: node.js, request, node-modules, async.js, superagent

I am not sure what the issue is but I think I have to make this async or promise based (idk how). I simply want to **pass the callback to http server on res.end**.
Can some one help please?

HTTP Request or SuperAgent passes the value to the function below. How to send this to http.createserver ?

```
function receiveCallback(link) {  
    console.log(link);
    //this works fine, echos the LINK we want to 302 to
}
```

How to pass **link** to http server?

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(302, {'Location': link});
  res.end();
}).listen('8080');
```

**Ex**. User opens domain.com/test?**somevar**

**somevar** is sent to superagent which then produces a **link**

How to 302 the user to the link

Comment: Can `receiveCallback()` be called multiple times, or just once at start?

Comment: Multiple times. Basically server passes url path to superagent, which then outputs a link I want the server to 302 to.

Comment: Almost like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243100/response-writehead-and-response-end-in-nodejs but how to insert my Link/Callback into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `superagent` is making its own request every time the server gets a request, it would look something like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const request = require('superagent');

http.createServer((req, res) => {

    const queryParams = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

    request
        .get('/get/my/link')
        .send({ somevar: queryParams.somevar })
        .end((err, response) => {

            if (err)
                throw err;

            const link = response.body.link;

            res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': link });
            res.end();
        });

}).listen('8080');
```

Comment: You cant call res.writeHead or res.end inside another function. I already tried. Console: TypeError: res.writeHead is not a function. 

That is why I rewrote the superagent code in pure http and same results.

Comment: Try this link on your get request. You should end up on google.com but it doesn't work. http://www.mocky.io/v2/59c17f8b1300005605d29e24

Comment: Fixed an error where there were 2 `res` variables in the same scope. All should be working now. Keep in mind this is just an example I came up with - it expects a response like this: http://www.mocky.io/v2/59c1874d130000b805d29e33

Comment: That is exactly why it wasn't working on original code too. 2 res. THANK YOUU